# Convert Entity Framework Properties to Dependency Properties

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-annotations, validation

I am working on a WPF application using MVVM pattern. I need to do data validation(using Data Annotations) for my data entry screens.

But the tricky part to write a common piece of code is rather than using simple property I need to use properties with are calling GetValue and SetValue method. But my entities are being generated by entity framework using templates and modifying template to achieve this things seems very difficult.

I am using this technique to validate my data

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/28/wpf-data-validation-using-net-data-annotations-part-ii.aspx

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/11/notifyingobject-for-wpf-amp-silverlight.aspx

If there is better and authentic way to validate the entity data, i'll be more than happy to change my approach or if I need to change the template then please point me to some great reference.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly. Really bad idea to do this, not because it is hard, but due to that you need to inherit `DependencyObject`. `DependencyObject` is an STA Threaded class. You won't be able to use a worker thread to instantiate your objects, which means you can't use a worker thread to use Entity Framework.

Now, I suggest you use the MVVM pattern with WPF. You should have a View bind to a ViewModel, which then binds to your Entity Framework POCO objects.

You can try `IValidateObject` for you validation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917890/mvc4-custom-validation-via-ivalidateobject-validate-method-not-working

I personally however prefer the FluentValidation library.